# Using the Hessian method to classify extremum points from Lagrange Multiplier Theorem

Tags: multivariable-calculus, lagrange-multiplier

I saw a few questions about classifying Lagrange Multiplier Theorem points, but none of them seem to address the Hessian specifically.

Say I use Lagrange Multiplier Theorem to minimize/maximize some function under some compact constraints and I get only one point. Assume that I can't assign some easy case to the function and compare it's values, and that I know the Hessian of the function in that point.

Can I classify the point as a maximum/minimum based on the eigenvalues of the Hessian?

Comment: You cannot use the second derivative test to classify critical points found using Lagrange multipliers. The reason for this is that usually a critical point on the constraint is not a critical point for the function, so the condition that each partial derivative is zero at that point is not satisfied.

Comment: Thanks @kccu. Totally missed that.